# how can i get query cliches in sql developer ?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I need the standard query like (insert , update , ...) for my table when I write sql in sql developer

I know I in sql server and mysql

like this 
INSERT INTO `student`(`std_name`, `id`, `GBA`) VALUES ([value-1],[value-2],[value-3])

Answer (score 0):

Let's use "insert" as an example..

When typing "insert" you could hold Ctrl (windows) to display any available code templates.

Take a look at the code templates if you wish to add more:

Tools > preferences > database > SQL Editor Code Templates